# Android: Block URL

Tags: android, parental-control

is it somehow possible to create an Android application / service that blocks an URL (or a list or URLs)?

From what I have searched here on StackOverflow and on Google it doesn't seems possible:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-security-discuss/ciepvxyn8UY

However, [Norton Safety Minder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.symantec.familysafety&hl=en) somehow "blocks" certain websites, although:

1. It lets the page load entirely before redirecting user (any idea on how they do it?)
2. It only seems to work for the stock browser (any ideia why? maybe they are listening for changes in the browser bookmark history?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it somehow possible to create an Android application / service that blocks an URL (or a list or URLs)?

Not really, for unrooted devices. With root, you might be able to rig up some iptables stuff to route things through some transparent proxy.

> It only seems to work for the stock browser (any ideia why? maybe they are listening for changes in the browser bookmark history?)

Given the one Play Store comment ("Going incognito mode bypasses the Web filters. Please fix."), that would be my guess. Script-kiddie techniques like that are never going to be reliable.